# How to model timeseries data in linear mixed effects model when you want to study the interaction of time with another variable?

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, interaction

Each data point is a 120-second long time series with gaze distribution over different visual targets for each of the frames (using 30fps). The response variable is memorability. So, for 1 single scenario, we have 3600 frames. My question is, what is the best way to model this if I want to see if the beginning 25 seconds is more indicative of memorability than the time after the first 25 seconds?

I process the data to make intervals of 5 seconds. So for a 120 seconds long scenario, I will have 24 intervals. For each 5 seconds interval, I aggregate the visual targets to get the proportions/distribution over different targets.

These are the relevant columns:

- time_stamp (categorical from 0 -> 23)
- memorability (0 or 1)
- robot (0 -> 1)
- screen (0 -> 1)
- other (0 -> 1)

The last three: **robot, screen, other** are the visual target distribution (in proportions) and they all add up to 1.

I tried to filter the data into two parts: first 25 seconds and after 25 seconds. Then, I made a model for each and tried to compare them to see if the former model was better than the latter. However, this was not possible as I used different datasets for different models.

```r
Error in anova.merMod(first25s.model, after25s.model) : models were 
    not all fitted to the same size of dataset
```

So, what is the best way to proceed, then? Can I just model it as follows:

```r
memorability ~ 1 + time_interval + gaze_distribution + 
    time_interval:gaze_distribution ...
```

This gives me an estimated parameter for the interaction but how can I interpret this to help me with the validation of my hypothesis: *if the beginning 25 seconds is more indicative of memorability than the time after the first 25 seconds*?